# div is not showing correctly

Tags: html, css

I have a div element I wish to incorporate into my page.

The div will contain text and a background image and I want each one on a new line with each one alternative from the left to the right

i.e.

```
Text box                  

                          Textbox

Text box
```

Here is the HTML code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- This is a comment tag -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Lecture 4</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="ok.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Black+Ops+One|Open+Sans:600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <header>
                <img src="logo.jpg" alt="company logo" />
                <h1>Mega Computers</h1>

                <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter Link" style="width:50px;height:50px;border:0;"></a> <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img src="facebook.png" alt="Twitter Link" style="width:50px;height:50px;border:0;"></a> <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img src="flickr.png" alt="Twitter Link" style="width:100px;height:50px;border:0;"></a> 
                    </header>
            <div id="main_body">
            <h1></h1>
            <div id="absolute">
            <h1>ok</h1>
            </div>
            <div id ="absolute2">
            <h1>ok</h1>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <ul>
                    <li>&copy; BB Industries Ltd 2015</li>
                </ul>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*<sup>Here is a pastebin containing the code: http://pastebin.com/pQN9vPfF</sup>*

However mine appears to be ignoring most of what I specified in the CSS, the background color and position are ignored, and there is no border. The relevant CSS is shown below

```cuss
div.absolute {
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

Most of these are being ignored, the text sits on the left instead of the right and all the features of the box are not shown. It effectively gives me a transparent area with some text in, which is not what I want.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: it is fixed please let it open

Comment: Can we recreate the whole issue with the code you have provided? If not,   See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @AlecBrice-Bateman Could we see the HTML you're using for the `div` and text?

Comment: edited in i hope this is what you need

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you address `<div id="absolute">` with `div.absolute` in the css. However, the `.` notation is for class names, not ids.

Solution:

- either change the id on the div to a class
- or change `div.absolute` in the css to `div#absolute` or just `#absolute`.

By the way, "absolute" is not the most terrific name for a div that is positioned relatively...